# How does SP_CONNECTION_STATE_DISCONNECTED work?

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

A question on the `connectionState` in `SPSession`: when does the session change to and from 
`SP_CONNECTION_STATE_DISCONNECTED`, i.e.:

`SP_CONNECTION_STATE_LOGGED_IN --> SP_CONNECTION_STATE_DISCONNECTED` and `SP_CONNECTION_STATE_LOGGED_IN <-- SP_CONNECTION_STATE_DISCONNECTED`?

1. Is it disconnected upon some kind of timeout, or does it simply mean that the AP isn't online?
2. If the session is in its `SP_CONNECTION_STATE_DISCONNECTED` state, do you have to invoke a login to move it to `SP_CONNECTION_STATE_LOGGED_IN` or does that happen whenever you try to do something against the AP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SP_CONNECTION_STATE_DISCONNECTED` is used for situations when you get booted off the backend for some reason - the most likely cause being the backend going down for maintenance or something similar.

When in this state, the library will try and reconnect on its own, and since we never take *all* of the backend sites down at once unless something truly catastrophic is going on, it'll likely switch back to `SP_CONNECTION_STATE_LOGGED_IN` in a few seconds.